# Why is 0.60792710 the maximum value that ts_rank() returns for an ORed tsquery?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Using the default weights, when any positive number of lexemes with label A are matched on a tsvector by an ORed tsquery (excluding any other matches), ts_rank() returns a probability of 6/Π².

The probabilities for other labels are just fractions of this constant, which corresponds to the maximum possible weight: 1.

If lexemes with other labels are also matched, the contribution of all matched A-labeled lexemes to the probability value is simply the constant multiplied times the fraction:

(number of tsquery lexemes matching on A-labeled tsvector lexemes) /
(total number of tsquery lexemes)

Matched lexemes with other labels add to the probability in a similar way, after adjusting the value of the constant using the corresponding weights.  Consequently, their contribution is always lower, yielding a probability less than the constant.

This reduction in probability is what you would expect when some query lexemes match on tsvector lexemes with lower weights.

So, 6/Π² is the maximum probability when ORing all query terms.  I'm curious as to why ts_rank() chooses this value as the upper probability limit.

PD: I know you can always go read the source and find hints in the comments, but maybe other people also find this a head-scratcher, and would appreciate a TL;DR here.